# NSPredicate crash after swift 3 migration

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

after migration to swift3, I have an issue that cannot fix

```
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
```

my App crashes on second line, bad access, no reason. types are right, no log, nothing, just bad access. any suggestions?

Found a reason, predicate is wrong, cause id is Int64 type, have no idea what kind of predicate I need for this version of swift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%@` format expect a *Foundation object* as argument, compare
["Predicate Format String Syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

You can bridge the `Int64` to `NSNumber`:

```
let id = Int64.max
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id as NSNumber)
print(predicate) // id == 9223372036854775807
```

or change the format to "long long":

```
let id = Int64.max
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %lld", id)
print(predicate) // id == 9223372036854775807
```

Bridging *all* number types to `NSNumber` is possible as of Swift 3.0.1 (Xcode 8.1) with the implementation of 
[SE-0139 Bridge Numeric Types to NSNumber and Cocoa Structs to NSValue](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md).

Comment: And FWIW, this means that the predicate was always wrong, and that the change with Swift 3 is in making it clear that it's wrong.

Comment: @TomHarrington it is a quite interesting, cause all works right