# Why is this predicate format being turned into '= nil'

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

It was suggested that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686005/nspredicate-crash-after-swift-3-migration) is an exact duplicate of my question however, my app wasn't crashing and I'm not migrating to Swift 3. It just wasn't returning any results. So the solution is essentially the same but the behavior on which my question is based is quite different.

After reading many threads this morning I'm pretty confident this code is correct and should work:

```
func fetchUnits(weightUnitUid: Int? = nil) -> [WeightUnit] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WeightUnit")
    if let weightUnitFilter = weightUnitUid {
        let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid = %@", weightUnitFilter)
        fetchRequest.predicate = filterPredicate
    }
```

but here's what it looks like in the debugging console:

> (lldb) po filterPredicate  // uid == nil

I'm passing in 0 and `weightUnitUid` is in fact 0 at this point so I'd expect:

> uid == 0

I know `%@` should be able to handle an NSNumber and that's what I need. Where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @MartinR, thank you for the answer but I don't think my question was an exact duplicate. The answer to solve the problem appears to be the same in this case, but my app wasn't crashing. It just wasn't returning any results. I also am not migrating to Swift 3.

Comment: I guess that if you would have tried with another value than 0, it should have crashed. It interpreted the %@ with 0 value as nil.

Comment: @Larme, probably true. But now that it works, I'm not going to touch it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%@` format expects a Foundation object as argument, the zero
is interpreted as `nil`.

You can convert the integer to `NSNumber`:

```
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid = %@", weightUnitFilter as NSNumber)
```

or use the "long int" format instead:

```
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid = %ld", weightUnitFilter)
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin. Both suggestions worked. I'm still not getting the result I expected but that calls for another question.