# NSPredicate to compare Int32

Tags: swift, nspredicate

```
elementFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pageId = %@",(Int32(pagesFromDb.first?.pageId)) !)
var Data = try moc.fetch(elementFetch as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Element]
```

I tried it with `%I`, `%d`, and converting to `Int` or number, nothing works.
Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Define "nothing works". Clearly explain what the issue is.

Comment: I am trying to compare a CoreData property as shown below with some INT32 value from a variable
 @NSManaged public var pageId: Int32
The comparison for string is working fine. But how do i compare a Int32 value is my question

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: Please try %i instead of %@ because i is for integer and @ for strings

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/41067122/1187415 ?

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are using the operator `%@` which is for Strings.
For integers use `%i` (not `%I`) as follows:

```
elementFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pageId = %i", pagesFromDb.first?.pageId)
```